# How to fix history of master?

Tags: git

I have the following scenario:
I made a cherry pick from master into branch A. Then I merged branch A (after some other commits) into master.
Now I can't directly push to master, cause rewriting history is not allowed.
How can I fix the master so i can push without rewriting history? I can get temporary rights to rewrite history.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What does the push error log say?

Comment: remote: Rewriting history is not allowed for branch refs/heads/master.
remote: Check your branch permissions configuration with the project administrator.

Comment: Are you alone to work on this project, to push on master ? Are you sure you merger branch A into master and not the opposite ? You should have done something like `git checkout master ; git merge A`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't need to rewrite history. You need to make all changes in your master to be after commits from origin master.

```
git fetch origin master:origin_master
git checkouf master
git rebase origin_master
git push origin master
```